# Linking method parameter with a class member in JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

In our company, there is a strict rule that everything has to be commented. This rule has some weak points such as duplicate texts. In order to avoid duplicate comments, I want to reference a method paramenter to a class member but could not find the proper solution.

When I link the class member in the method parameter and hover the method parameter,

```
  /**
   * I would like to see this comment
   */
  private int       lineNumber;

  /**
   * Creates a new {@link GroupByMetaData} object.
   *
   * @param aLineNumber {@link GroupByMetaData#lineNumber}
   */
  public GroupByMetaData( int aLineNumber )
  {
    super();
    this.lineNumber = aLineNumber;
  }
```

The following result is;

[image]

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Comment: `@see` maybe???

Comment: @RC. I have read some articles and the mostly, it is said that see tag should be used to link other closely related classes whose Javadocs would give the reader a clearer picture of the purpose of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to copy one item’s javadoc into another, except for `{@inheritDoc}` which can only insert from the superclass documentation of the same item.

The fact that the constructor sets a private int field is part of the internal implementation.  Your javadoc should not mention, or `{@link}` to, a private field;  rather the javadoc should describe it conceptually.

The private javadoc usually is not the same as the public javadoc.  Private javadoc will contain important details of implementation that shouldn’t be seen by general users of the class.  For instance:

```
/**
 * Line of input this object will analyze.  This is never negative.
 * Controls the loops in the `read` method and the `translate` method.
 */
private int lineNumber;
```

Comment: Is there any way to link it if the lineNumber field were public field instead of private?

Comment: I’m afraid not.  There is only `{@inheritDoc}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sometimes, to know that it is not possible is also benefical:)